# How do I add 3rd party libraries with gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to learn gradle from [this site](http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) but I do not know how to add a source for 3rd party libraries. Should I add the following to the `build.gradle` file?

```js
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-gradle'
    version =  '2.3'
}
```

Comment: Just go to the very end of the guide where the final version of the `build.gradle` file is shown. This confirms that indeed your assumptions are correct so far.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend learning gradle from their [official site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html) which contains more comprehensive documentation than the Spring site. After grasping the basics of gradle you can venture into using gradle for a  Spring project as it adds complexity on top of plain gradle especially when using the Spring boot plugin.

In order to add dependencies to a (Java) project you have to get the GAV coordinates (**G**roupId:**A**rtifactId:**V**ersion). These can be obtained from the project websites or directly from the public (maven) repositories. The popular [jCenter()](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) and [mavenCentral()](http://search.maven.org/) are already build in.

Definining a repository is done using the repositories block:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Then you have to specify to which [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:configurations) you want to add you dependency; the following snippet adds joda-time to the build-in compile configuration which means that it will be added to the compile classpath:

```
dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
}
```

So yes, your script is correct for adding the joda-time library but it might be a good idea to delve further into the gradle documentation to understand what it does.